# File upload in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload

I need do to simple loading of files to public folder. There are many gems, but all them (and tutorials) show how to do this using model etc... But i need simple chose file in view, and send it to controller, which generate random name and save it to public folder, without any model and so over. Simple chose - upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [carrier wave without active record,](http://blog.endpoint.com/2012/04/using-carrierwave-without-orm.html) or

You can write manually to to public folder,you can read file using `params[:file_name].tempfile` it's rack multipart object you can inspect by putting debugger or pry

Comment: hm, could you write more detaily second variant (how to get via params i know), but how to write, generate name and save it?

Comment: you can open a file/fileutils  with some random name,and read from tempfile and write content to open file

Comment: you can refer and if you want you can change code as per your need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704143/rails-3-get-raw-post-data-and-write-it-to-tmp-file

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415895/uploading-a-raw-file-to-rails-using-carrierwave